# Install Lazarus under UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, lazarus

I installed  the Code Typhon latest version  on a UBUNTU VM ware installation following the instructions given here step by step  [install under UBUNTU](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/wiki/135-wiki/codetyphon-host-oses/610-ct-on-ubuntu-18-04-budgie) . 
Under Windows the code typhon IDE works fine but now under LINUX whatever function I call - the function  is ending in an endless loop without any response finally.

What is wrong with my Code typhon installation ?

[image: CodeTyphon CENTER for LUNUX]

Comment: Your q title refers to Lazarus, but you seem to be asking about CodeTyphon.  Anyway, Lazarus (including FPC) installs fine in Ubuntu using apt-get - see the instructions on the Lazarus/fpc website.  Don't know about CodeTyphon, though.

Comment: installed  now Lazarus on my VM ware , also got memory issue for compiling first app, this lead to my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the reason for not responing CODE TYPHON CENTER

Increased memory for UBUNTU VM ware , after restart new installtion wo any issues

1. default (not working settings)  memory 1 GByte  new working setting
2. memory 3 Gbyte
3. sometimes it helped to run CTC as root, you need toprovide password
   for sudo